# configure mdadm for existing intel rapid storage array

Tags: intel, mdadm

i have a raid 1 configured by intel rapid storage from the bios.

with windows i have an application which manage the raid.

i read about intel rapid storage for linux and found that the option is to install mdadm.

now i'm trying to apply the configuration in ubuntu but i haven't found how to do it.

i don't want to break the raid or recreate it.

someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

**dmraid** is the primary toolset which drives platform independent software RAID aka "Fake RAID". mdadm can handle *some* of the fake RAID formats, you likely need to manually assemble the RAID. See **man mdadm**.

http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/cs-020663.htm

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to use Intel Matrix Storage Management capable drives is via *mdadm*

You can do so safely with mdadm in Quantal (3.2.5)

Or install the quantal version in precise (pending an sru)

Or you can compile from source.

Comment: can you please explain in detail what is quantal?

Comment: @idgar the package named 'mdadm' can be used to setup Intel Matrix Storage Management. Sufficiently new version of this package is available in Quantal.

Comment: Yeah, but I cannot figure out the device names https://askubuntu.com/questions/794763/how-to-determine-device-name-for-nmve-ssds-during-install

Answer (score 1):

ok, after determining again the situation, i've understood that my Intel Rapid Storage mirror RAID has been configured as dmraid because the first time i've configured it was for windows 7 (intel rapid storage software for windows support only dmraid variation).

i've managed to see the details by running "sudo dmraid -s".

my RAID device is listed as /dev/dm-0 (and linked from /dev/mapper/isw_[raid set]_[array's name from BIOS]

in case of failure, i saw that in order to rebuild the RAID one need to run "sudo dmraid -R [raid set]

"sudo dmraid -r" will show which devices listed as part of raid sets.

[Intel Rapid Storage in Linux PDF](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/PAPERS/326024.pdf)

Comment: a good article about intel rapid storage and dmraid: [link](http://techie.org/Blog/2010/09/03/how-to-rebuild-intel-raid-isw-on-linux/)